# Selenium - How to get pixel color?

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, pixel

For a web based application such as youtube, metacafe, or an audio streaming where progress bar gets displayed, i want to capture whether it has actually played or not.

I was thinking of :

1. Going to the link
2. Click on play button
3. Move the mouse to a specific position, and Capture a pixel color on the player.
4. Wait for x no. of seconds
5. Capture the same pixel color again.

But right now I don't see any way to do it. the whole progress bar gets displayed as a single object.  Is there any I can achieve this?

Comment: Most audio streaming players use Flash, so Selenium isn't going to work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the background color of progress bar using CSS property of the object using following code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Xpath")).getCssValue("Background-Color")
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, additional question on that, will it not give the pixels for the entire player?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `driver.get_screenshot_as_png` to get a picture (in binary format), and use PIL to analyze it.
This method may be dumb, but I couldn't find any better solution.